# Unable to store data in cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to store data in cloud firestore. Authentication is all correct but the data is not going in cloud firestore and because of that login also not working because cloud firestore is pre-req to login function

That's my AuthContoller function

```
storeUserData({name, password, email}) async {
    DocumentReference store = firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    store.set(
        {'name': name, 'password': password, 'email': email, 'imageUrl': ''});
  }
```

and that's my signup button code

```
 try {
                                  await controller
                                      .signupMethod(
                                    context: context,
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    password: passwordController.text,
                                  )
                                      .then((value) {
                                    ** return controller
                                        .storeUserData(
                                            email: emailController.text,
                                            name: nameController.text,
                                            password: passwordController.text)
                                        .then((value) {
                                      VxToast.show(context,
                                          msg: 'Account Created Sucessfully');
                                      Get.offAll(LoginScreen());
                                    }); **
                                  });
                                } catch (e) {
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                                  VxToast.show(context, msg: e.toString());
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```html
storeUserData({name, password, email}) async {
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await _firestore.collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).set(
        {'name': name, 'password': password, 'email': email, 'imageUrl': ''});
  }
```